# Why I got this linker warning?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

directory not found for option '-F"/business/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNew/..

This is the full error

```
Ld /Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-hisqcnecwuovfqblviqcirmbwgsy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hello.app/hello normal i386
    cd /business/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNew
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-hisqcnecwuovfqblviqcirmbwgsy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/business/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNew/Twitter/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries\ &\ Headers -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/lib/system -F/Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-hisqcnecwuovfqblviqcirmbwgsy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/business/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNew -F/Users/Teguh/Documents/FacebookSDK -F\"/business/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNew/..\" -F/Users/Teguh/Dropbox/badgers -filelist /Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-hisqcnecwuovfqblviqcirmbwgsy/Build/Intermediates/BadgerNew.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/hello.build/Objects-normal/i386/hello.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lsqlite3.0 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework FacebookSDK -framework Twitter -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreText -weak_framework Social -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework Accounts -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -lxml2 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-hisqcnecwuovfqblviqcirmbwgsy/Build/Intermediates/BadgerNew.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/hello.build/Objects-normal/i386/hello_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Teguh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BadgerNew-hisqcnecwuovfqblviqcirmbwgsy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hello.app/hello
```

It seems that somewhere in project settings, I must have an option called -F"/business/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNew/..

I wonder how.

Comment: When you are getting this error??

Comment: When compiling the program.

Comment: search `business/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNew` in your project settings. you can even open the project file using plain text editor and search the string there

Comment: More specifically, in your project settings under project -> BadgerNew and Target -> BadgerNew look at: other linker flags,  header search paths and library search paths